# Orthogonal complement between two sets?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, stochastic-calculus

In Kallenberg's textbook on Modern Probability, chapter 11, pg. 217, he makes use of the following notation, highlighted in yellow, mentioning before that the symbol means "orthogonal complement". What does this mean, in the context of having sets on either side?

[image]

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @SBF oops, editted.

Comment: Sound like $A = B \ominus C$ if $B = C \oplus A$ at least on the level of homeomorphisms

Comment: This notation is defined in the chapter on conditional probability

Comment: Orthogonal complement.  If $F \subset E$ are two closed subspaces of a Hilbert space, then define $E \ominus F := E \cap F^{\perp}$.